# Parsing JSON with same tag name using C#

Tags: c#, json

I am Writing a Code using C# that will Parse JSON Code and create it as objects.

I have this JSON Example

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName" : "Smith",
     "age"      : 25,
     "address"  :
     {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city"         : "New York",
         "state"        : "NY",
         "postalCode"   : "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber":
     [
         {
           "type"  : "home",
           "number": "212 555-1234"
         },
         {
           "type"  : "fax",
           "number": "646 555-4567"
         }
     ]
 }
```

as you can see there is multible numbers, some Person have 1 telephone numbers, some others has 4 or 5.

I know i should do a While Loop, but can i get how many Phones are inside the Phone number to use it a counter to add these phones to PhoneNumber Object that i created?

Comment: `phoneNumber` is an *Array* of `{type"  : "..","number": ".." }`

Comment: Well how are you doing the parse, do you really need to know how many phone numbers would be there ?

Comment: I am doing the parse using NEWTONSOFT.JSON, this is how i do the parse

PhoneNumber is a class i created, and I have another Class Called Person that has a instance variable as List<PhoneNumber>

Comment: Are you doing as an exercise or a homework? Because there are libraries which already do this for you.

Comment: i am doing this as a Self project, and I am using NEWTONSOFT.JSON, i think this one is good

Comment: Take a look over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984337/json-net-selecting-items-in-array-with-linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NEWTONSOFT.JSON, you can get an array of PhoneNumber by this code

```
JArray sa = (JArray)o["person"]["phoneNumbers"]["phoneNumber"];
```

and this get number of phonenumber availables by

```
sa.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Json.Net for parsing json, than first you should create the following create and and deserialize the json into the following Contact Object, after deserializing into the contact object every thing will be straight forward.

```
public class Contact
{
  public string firstName { get; set; }
  public string lastName { get; set; }
  public int age { get; set; }
  public address address { get; set; };
  public List<phoneNumber> phoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class address
{
     public string streetAddress { get; set; }
     public string city { get; set; }
     public string state { get; set; }
     public string postalCode { get; set; }
}


public class phoneNumber
{
     public string type { get; set; }  
     public string number { get; set; }
}


var contact = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(data);
var count = contact.phonenumber.Count;
```

Comment: @Asef, regarding your solution, i think it will be the best if it work, but i tried it, the deserializeObject type contacts, it gives me null.